# Getting only one line i.e Configure Successfully message in postman in json but when added in json file for asserting its taking as invalid

Tags: json, api, rest-assured

So I got a response from the API, configure Successfully (like this only with no quotations or flower brackets) in JSON format in Postman.

I want to assert this in REST Assured, using a JSON file, but its telling its a invalid format , I have tried multiple String to JSON formatters, but all give the same invalid response.

And when asserted, the test fails.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You cannot just take anything to `{}` to have it jsoned. Check [this](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) to learn the proper JSON syntax. If you response is not JSON, you should not use JSON to verify that.

Comment: I did not do that, I downloaded it from postman itself.

Comment: Show the response headers